# HTML form: onblur event does not work when id and name changed

Tags: html, forms, attributes

I have this HTML form which works fine when written like this:

```html
<fieldset>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onblur="validateName(name)" />
  <span id="nameError" style="display: none;">You can only use alphabetic characters, hyphens and apostrophes</span>
</fieldset>
```

But when I change 3rd and 4th line to:

```html
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" onblur="validateName(firstname)" />

<span id="firstnameError" style="display: none;">You can only use alphabetic characters, hyphens and apostrophes</span>
```

, onblur doesn't work! How could it be? After all i just changed the name and ID?

This is my validateName(name) function:

```js
function validateName(x) {
  // Validation rule
  var re = /[A-Za-z -']$/;
  // Check input
  if (re.test(document.getElementById(x).value)) {
    // Style green
    document.getElementById(x).style.background = '#ccffcc';
    // Hide error prompt
    document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "none";
    return true;
  } else {
    // Style red
    document.getElementById(x).style.background = '#e35152';
    // Show error prompt
    document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "block";
    return false;
  }
}
```

thanks

Comment: interesting. Clear your browser cache and try again.

Comment: did you debug your code using browser ? You may find the error causing. I believe it is a js error.

Comment: I cleared the cashe but it didn't work. But the solution that Mr. @panther provided solved my problem. Thanks to him and you too for trying to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change ID of error element too (because of `x + Error`).

```
<span id="firstnameError"...>
```

And put function params into quotes:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" onblur="validateName('firstname')" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lgp55uwo/

Comment: @KhatarnaakGunda: okay, and put function param into quotes, it's string. `onblur="validateName('firstname')`.

Comment: I love you :D it worked. I added quotes as you said.

Comment: Can I ask you why it worked the first time when it was just name? It had no quotes at that time.

Comment: Also if you don't mind may I ask what actually are we passing in that parameter? name or ID? I ask this because firstname is the name and also the ID. Thanks

Comment: @KhatarnaakGunda: ID, see the 7th line in your JS - there is `getElementBbyId(x)` and x is the function parameter.

Comment: Thank you @panther I figured it out.